# Post a private message to the user frined using Ruby and fb_graph gem?

Tags: ruby, facebook

I want to send a private message to a user's friend using [fb_graph](https://github.com/nov/fb_graph). In the docs I can see how to send a post in the users wall but not how to send a message on behalf of that user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it cannot be done; Facebook removed the functionality due to abuse (spam etc).

Please refer to: [how send message facebook friend through graph api using Accessstoken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943297/how-send-message-facebook-friend-through-graph-api-using-accessstoken)

Comment: actually it is possible, there are some app able to do that

Answer (score 2):

You can use Facebook Chat API to send private messages, here is an example in Ruby using xmpp4r_facebook gem:

```
sender_chat_id = "-#{sender_uid}@chat.facebook.com"
receiver_chat_id = "-#{receiver_uid}@chat.facebook.com"
message_body = "message body"
message_subject = "message subject"

jabber_message = Jabber::Message.new(receiver_chat_id, message_body)
jabber_message.subject = message_subject

client = Jabber::Client.new(Jabber::JID.new(sender_chat_id))
client.connect
client.auth_sasl(Jabber::SASL::XFacebookPlatform.new(client,
   ENV.fetch('FACEBOOK_APP_ID'), facebook_auth.token,
   ENV.fetch('FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET')), nil)
client.send(jabber_message)
client.close
```

Comment: allways see "RuntimeError: not-authorized" exception: xmpp4r_facebook.rb:103:in `auth'

Answer (score 0):

It seems that is not possible but posting to the user's wall might be an alternative: https://github.com/nov/fb_graph/issues/issue/28/#comment_591398