# BranchOut/Glassdoor Facebook Friend-network Invite Integration

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, json

How do companies like BranchOut/Glassdoor implement protocols for mass referrals of friends through networks? Aren't all Facebook applications limited to the Requests Dialog for user referrals? As far as I know, we aren't able to use FQL/PHP to refer users through the Open Graph API either (BranchOut/Glassdoor still send out user-pushed application notifications nonetheless).

[image]

EDIT: Requested self-close on question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My name is Ali and I am BranchOut's Community Manager. I want to clarify that we use the standard Facebook dialog request to send invites. The user sees exactly what is going to be sent to the recipients before invites are sent out. There is no auto-invite process on our part. If you have any additional questions, I am happy to be a resource, community@branchout.com

Answer (score 0):

You can't send messages directly to all the friends of a user however they are other options.

These answers give you a number of options: [how send message facebook friend through graph api using Accessstoken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943297/how-send-message-facebook-friend-through-graph-api-using-accessstoken)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's *different* in their approach?

They only have a custom friends selector, and once you click "Include them":

```
BranchOut.GroupConnect = {
    //...
    submit: function (srcEl) {
        // collect selected recipeints code here
        AppRequest.send(this.recipientUidsArray.join(','), 'Invite Friends', 'would like to add you as a professional connection ', 'XXX', callback);
    },
    //...
}
```

And that would just open the [Requests Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/):

```
AppRequest = {
    //...
    send: function (uid, title, message, data, callback) {
        FB.ui({
            display: 'iframe',
            method: 'apprequests',
            new_style_message: true,
            title: title,
            message: message,
            to: uid,
            data: data
        }, function (r) {
            if (r != null && typeof (r) != 'undefined') {
                if (r.request) {
                    AppRequest.sendCallback(r);
                    if (callback.success) callback.success(r);
                }
            }
        });
        AppRequest.setYCount = 0;
        AppRequest.setLastDialogY();
    },
    //...
}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Any idea what the new_style_message stands for? Usually if the person is not a use of your app they will see "Jon invited you to us Brachout". Instead of the full message. However, Bracnhout always get's their custom message displayed - even if the person hasn't signed up yet.