# Send message to a facebook user who is not your friend yet

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

If you go to someone's Facebook profile there is a button that allows you to send a message to them even if you are not their friend.  With Facebook's SDK, is it possible to send a message to these individuals using my account details?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [how send message facebook friend through graph api using Accessstoken](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943297/how-send-message-facebook-friend-through-graph-api-using-accessstoken)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I think you can, but only if they had not changed their permissions.
 (Read More About Permissions: [here](https://www.facebook.com/help/?page=168044269923334));
To send the message; here is a similar question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943297/how-send-message-facebook-friend-through-graph-api-using-accessstoken)

Answer (score 0):

Like says @agam360, permisson read_mailbox is necessary.

Read this http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/message/

But I'm not found in doc, the section about send messages, only about read it. I believe that dont be possible make this. You could to post on wall?