# Send a message to a friend, I wonder Javascript API

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am a developer from the Republic of Korea.

I am currently making Facebook and Twitter-based websites.

I want to use a JavaScript API that can send message to friends,

So I consulted the `iframe` Javascript API methods or using Facebook page looked as sending.

I wonder,

I use to send messages to friends as a Javascript API that provides a?

I do not know English well. So I used Google translator.

Please understand.

`(Edited, fixed some grammar and  rewording)`

```js
FB.api (path, "post", {

        message: msg,

        caption: "caption caption",

        link: "http://www.naver.com",

        description: "Description Description",

        picture: "http://sstatic.naver.net/search/img3/h1_naver.gif",

        tag: "Tag",

        name: "name names",

        access_token: accessToken

        }, Function (response) {

        if (! response | | response.error){

            alert ("error");

        }

        else{

            alert (response.id);

        }

    })
```

Comment: Do you want a javascript library that will send a message to multiple recipients on facebook?

Comment: Somnath Muluk - plug-in no~no~ / library ok!! ^^;

Answer (score 3):

You want to send a message to a friend on Facebook, or post to the Facebook wall for all to see? I am going to assume sending a message to a friend on Facebook.

**Manual**

If you want to send a message to friends on Facebook using the JS SDK, follow these instructions: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/

This isn't automatic and will still show a dialog box for the user to confirm.

**Automatic**

If you wanted to do it in the background via the Graph API, you can't. Here is a link explaining it in further detail why you can't and other options you have: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4061298/540339

Comment: Answer Thank you.
But
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/
Approach using the iframe & facebook page sends a message.
I want to spend on my page.

Comment: If you want custom code and your own send dialog box then this isn't possible. If you wanted the send button you use this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/send/

Comment: :) Thanks, Adam
Resolve plug-in, but I want
Sent directly to my page function.