# Send a private message to a friend using Facebook Graph API with send dialog URL option doesn't work

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I know that this subject has been raised a lot, and i have read all the posts related, and still didn't got a clear answer.

So in brief, my windows store app uses a user's permission to login with their facebook account, then i get all of their friends for him to see.
Now, i want him to be able to send a message to one of his friends.
From all the many posts that i saw, i've encountered this famouse post:
[how send message facebook friend through graph api using Accessstoken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943297/how-send-message-facebook-friend-through-graph-api-using-accessstoken)
Which was exectly what i wanted, but i understand that facebook is not allowing to send a message via 'send dialog' any more..
So what are my alternatives? how can i send a message to a friend? by email? by a wall post?
what perrmissions do i need? I've tried it all with no success..

I'm not using any SDK, it's all from my windows store app; until now i've used URL's via graph API, for example, to retreive the logged in user's friends data:

```
string request = string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?fields=first_name,last_name,id,picture.width(180).height(180)&access_token={0}", token);
```

Thanks.

Comment: What makes you say the send dialog doesn't work anymore? it should, and you can prefill a single user ID too

Comment: Sorry, my bad. 
The redirect URL i gave was broken, and the error message that i was getting didn't supply that information. 
case closed. I'm going to bash my head into a wall.
Any one knows which field do i have to use to pre populate the message box? the "message=MY_MESSAGE" didn't work.

Comment: You can't - you set the app-supplied text via the meta tags on the URL you're asking the user to send - the user's message can't be prefilled in the dialog ( and prefilling it directly in the other parts of the API is against policy )

Comment: Yeah i realized it later.. thanks for the help anyway Igy

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the comments, you must ensure you have a valid redirect URL. Without this, the send action will not work.