# Facebook API method: How can I send private messages to multiple friends using FB.api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I want to send a private messages to my friends silently. So, I prefer FB.api method to send.

But, I could not find the best solution for my problem.

Send Dialog api sends in FB.ui method and can't send more than 1 at a time. It expects a form submission.

Feed Dialog api is a public post. I think, I'm right.

My exact scenario is, I have huge number of messages in my app. I will select and send to my friends. It would not displayed on their wall. I mean it should not be a public. It should be a private message.

Please send your ideas.

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2574431/send-private-messages-to-friends

Comment: Thanks. But, they have used FB.UI method. some one said we cant.

Comment: Hey check this out.. This might solve or answer your problem..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943297/how-send-message-facebook-friend-through-graph-api-using-accessstoken

Comment: Thanks Newbie. I'll check it out.

Comment: I think, we can't send private messages to our friends.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this topic? I'm exactly in the same scenario. thanks  !!

Comment: Yes, but it is impossible in FB.API method. So I prefer to use FB.UI Send method.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook do not provide any api for this, but provide chat api, so you can send messages via it.
for more details see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/