# Facebook Send Dialog - custom name, description

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm trying set a custom description and name when sending link using FB Send Dialog.

```
FB.ui({
method: 'send',
name: 'Custom name',
display: 'popup',
link: 'http://link.com',
to: facebookUserId,
description: 'Custom desc.'
}
```

However, Send Dialog ignores custom name and description and uses title and "meta" description from link. When I first used Send Dialog (3 weeks ago) custom text and description were shown. I haven't made any changes since then.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I know this is not an answer to your question but can you consider using meta tags instead of manually setting the title/description? There are lots of advantages by doing this, for example it is easier to manage what's displayed, a small change doesn't need to change many modules posting messages and if someone copy/paste your link in Facebook the title/description/image will be automatically displayed.

Comment: I know but it's a client's wish :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dialog is ignoring those fields because it does not support them. If it did work previously, you can attribute it to Facebook's documentation being inexact (that happens quite a lot).

I believe you are confusing the Send and Feed dialogs. There are no "name" and "description" parameters for the Send dialog. Only `to` and `link`. This is mentioned in [the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/).

Whereas on the [Feed dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/), you are able to supply all the fields you mention.

You can still use the Feed dialog and specify a `to` parameter to get the same functionality.

Comment: Yes, I've found it in the documentation today. But I believe it has changed recently. I followed this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943297/how-send-message-facebook-friend-through-graph-api-using-accessstoken#9328262 when creating my Send Dialog. `Properties` where copied from documentation.

Comment: @pet - that post was from over a year ago. The relevant documentation was updated about a month ago. It is very possible that the feature has changed since...

Comment: As a Facebook developer, you really have to keep watch and follow the [developers roadmap](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap) to keep upto date on any changes...

Comment: It also stopped working for me. Looks like Facebook suddenly stopped supporting them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'send',
    name: 'Custom name',
    link: 'http://link.com',
    to: facebookUserId,
    description: 'Custom desc.'
});
```

Facebook Developer Reference

**display**

Determines how the dialog is rendered.

- If you are using the URL redirect dialog implementation, then this will be a full page display, shown within Facebook.com. This display type is called page.
- If you are using one of our iOS or Android SDKs to invoke the dialog, this is automatically specified and chooses an appropriate display type for the device.
- If you are using the JavaScript SDK, this will default to a modal iframe type for people logged into your app or async when using within a game on Facebook.com, and a popup window for everyone else. You can also force the popup or page types when using the JavaScript SDK, if necessary.
- Mobile web apps will always default to the touch display type.

[Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/)

Comment: How is this different from what the OP posted?

Comment: I am using same but display is not there

Comment: You just use default display. I need `popup` for my site.

Comment: @aka - you should really add some explanations. Just throwing some code into an answer is not the best way to help someone.. Take another 2 mins and explain what you changed and what your reasons are.

Comment: Yes, you're right. But custom description is not working. Using older API, default value was `page`.