# Facebook Send Call with Custom Description

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Sorry if there is an existing solution, but I keep reading that the Facebook API does not support this ([e.g.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17923242/facebook-send-dialog-custom-name-description)), but:

How do you add a custom description to a Facebook Send Call? I know it must be possible, because [ESPN does it on their site.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cL9gT.jpg)

How are they doing it? I have tried using the OpenGraph tags but nothing shows up on my page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never could figure this out - it looks like Facebook disallowed the feature some time ago.