# how to send message for particular user id on facebook in restful web services

Tags: facebook, wcf

i have develop restful web services to send message on particular facebook friend ,but i am unable to send message on particular facebook id.

```
            FacebookClient app = new FacebookClient(accessToken);
            dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
            parameters.description = "hellos friens !!!!";
            dynamic result = app.Post("https://graph.facebook.com/100006251015838/feed", parameters);
```

when i using above code i am getting this error,

(OAuthException - #200) (#200) Feed story publishing to other users is disabled for this application

please help me what should have solution for this..

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately facebook do not allow to send messages to friends from server side.

This has been responded here: [how send message facebook friend through graph api using Accessstoken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943297/how-send-message-facebook-friend-through-graph-api-using-accessstoken)

Comment: Can i send the any notification to particular facebook friend?

Comment: No you can ´t, There is the chat api but i don ´t think this is what you where looking for: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/

Comment: Can i get email address for the facebook friend using facebook id ?

Comment: No besides the ones that have made their email public.